# Eloquent relationship and class with constructor

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, laravel-5.5, has-many

I have two classes which are connected through hasMany and belongsTo method.

```
class InquiryParameter extends Model
{
    public function translations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InquiryParameterTranslation::class);
    }
}
```

---

```
class InquiryParameterTranslation extends Model
{
    public function __construct($inquiry_parameter_id, $language_code, $name, $description)
    {
            $this->inquiry_parameter_id = $inquiry_parameter_id;
            $this->language_code = $language_code;
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->description = $description;
    }
}
```

---

However, when I create new object

`$inquiry_parameter = new InquiryParameter;`

And then call method translations.

```
$names = $inquiry_parameter->translations;
```

I received error:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function
>   App\InquiryParameterTranslation::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /Users/SouL-MAC/Code/konfig/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php
>   on line 653 and exactly 4 expected (View:
>   /Users/SouL-MAC/Code/konfig/resources/views/admin/inquiry/parameters.blade.php)

Is it possible to use eloquent relationship with classes which contains constructor ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: i think you need `parent::__construct(...)` in your models constructor

Comment: BTW: this seems to be wrong: `$inquiry_parameter = new InquiryParameter;`. It should be something like this: `$inquiry_parameter = new InquiryParameter($inquiry_parameter_id, $language_code, $name, $description);`

Comment: It's for InquiryParameterTranslation, I don't have constructor for class InquiryParameter yet

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52293260/5013099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$names = $inquiry_parameter->translations;

When above code runs, it actually creates a new object of Class InquiryParameterTranslation without passing any parameters to constructor. But your constructor expects parameters. Therefore it is causing error.

Solution to this problem is that you change your constructor code as given below:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // no parameter in constructor
}
```

Then create another function (as given below) to initialize model properties

```
public function initialize($inquiry_parameter_id, $language_code, $name, $description)
{
        $this->inquiry_parameter_id = $inquiry_parameter_id;
        $this->language_code = $language_code;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
}
```

By making above changes your code will run fine and when you need to add new translation to database you can use following code (Example)

```
$translation = new InquiryParameterTranslation;
$translation->initialize($inquiry_parameter_id, $language_code, $name, $description);

$translation->save();
```

Comment: That's it, i do it like this, but i hope i could use constructor itself. So i think, it's not possible to use constructor with eloquent relationship. Thank you.

Comment: But if I want to use constructor to create model object is this not possible when using relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending a given object which already has a constructor, you need to call it with the corresponding attributes.
See the API for [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method___construct)

Try something like this:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
        parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

In your particular case the following would work:

```
public function __construct($inquiry_parameter_id, $language_code, $name, $description)
{
        parent::__construct();

        $this->inquiry_parameter_id = $inquiry_parameter_id;
        $this->language_code = $language_code;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
}
```

Comment: i put constructor to Model class and parent::__construct(); to InquiryParameterTranslation constructor and it is the same as previous